# QGIS 3 relationship strength "Composition"

Tags: qgis-3

is there somebody who can explain the usage of the relationship strength "Composition" in QGIS 3? What can the user do in detail when setting to "Composition"?

> Relationship strength sets the strength of the relation between the
> parent and the child layer. The default Association type means that
> the parent layer is simply linked to the child one while the
> Composition type allows you to duplicate also the child features when
> duplicating the parent ones.

This is only a short description. I checked out to copy and paste a polygon feature with a relation to a point feature (relationship strength "Composition"). Failed.

Answer (score 5):

I think you can find answers to this in the data modelling and database literature.
In UML, a *composition* is a specialisation of an *association* (introducing constraints).

https://www.visual-paradigm.com/guide/uml-unified-modeling-language/uml-aggregation-vs-composition/ explains it like this:

`Composition implies a relationship where the child cannot exist independent of the parent. Example: House (parent) and Room (child). Rooms don't exist separate to a House.`

Since a child object can't exists without the parent object, it will be deleted if the parent object is deleted.
To dive deeper, you could try to search for "relationship composition association".

I have not looked into how this is implemented in QGIS, but since this terminology is used, I would assume that the object-oriented modelling "rules" are followed.

Answer (score 1):

This will tell QGIS how children will be handled, when parents are duplicated/deleted.

With association, children are ignored. With composition, children are also duplicated/deleted.